# How to calculate the sum of column whose date is same?

Tags: jsp

I want to get the sum of a column whose dates are same.

Date                     Charges
3/8/2012                  200
3/8/2012                  400
4/8/2012                  300
4/8/2012                  100

```
<%stat=con.createStatement();
rs=stat.executeQuery("select * from pat.dbo.PHPL"); 
while(rs.next())
{
date=rs.getString("Date");
charges=rs.getString("Charges");%>
<table>

<tr>
<td><%=date%></td>
<td><%=charges%></td>
<%}%>
</tr></table>
```

Want this result:

Date                     Charges
3/8/2012                  600
4/8/2012                  400

I want this with jsp not in sql query. As I set datatype of charges as String in database. So sum was not be possible in query.
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean in jsp ?? you will still need to get this from the database no? how do get the data in jsp? do you have objects including this information

Comment: Is the table you give the input or the output? I assume it’s the input, but what then is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give any information about dbms you are using but, by your original query, I assume you are using sqlserver from Microsoft.

So, you can write:

select date, sum(cast(charges as float)) from pat.dbo.PHPL group by date.
See this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the solution of José Esteves-Pereira by conversion, but you can try this utnested code:

```
<%stat=con.createStatement();
rs=stat.executeQuery("select * from pat.dbo.PHPL");
actDate
while(rs.next())
{
  date = rs.getString("Date");
  if (actDate != date)
  {
    actDate = date;
    charges = rs.getString("Charges");
  }
  else
  {
    charges += rs.getString("Charges");
  }
%>
<table>

<tr>
<td><%=actDate %></td>
<td><%=charges%></td>
<%}%>
</tr>
</table>
```